# Invertibility of an operator in a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X \subset Y$ be Banach spaces and exists constant $C > 0$, such that $\|x\|_Y$ $\leq$$C\|x\|_X$ $\quad$ $\forall x \in X$ (then the operator $J: X \rightarrow Y$, $Jx= x$, is continuous, i.e. the space X is embedded in Y). Under what conditions on the spaces $X$ and $Y$ the operator $J$ has a right inverse, left reverse? It feels, that for right invertibility it is necessary and sufficient that $X = Y$, for right invertibility it is necessary and sufficient that $X$ is a closed complemented subspace of $Y$. But I'm unable prove it strictly, can someone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R:Y\to X$ denote the right inverse of $J.$ Then
$y=JRy=Ry.$ Therefore $R$ acts as identity on $Y$ which is equivalent to $X=Y.$

Let $L:Y\to X$ denote the left inverse of $J.$   We have $x=LJx=  Lx.$  Hence $X={\rm Im}L$ and $Y/\ker L$ is algebraically isomorphic to $X.$ By the continuity of $L$ we get $$\|x\|_X=\|L(x+z)\|_X\le c \|x+z\|_Y,\ \ x\in X,\ z\in \ker L$$ Hence $$\|x\|_X\le c|x+z\|_Y,\quad x\in X,\ z\in \ker L$$ and $$\|x\|_X\le c\,{\rm dist}_Y\,(x,\ker L)\le c\|x\|_Y$$ Therefore the norms $\|\cdot \|_X$ and $\|\cdot \|_Y$ are equivalent on $X,$ which implies that $X$ is closed in $Y.$

We will show that $Y$ is isomorphic to $X\oplus \ker L,$ as Banach spaces, with the norm
$$\|x\oplus z\|_{X\oplus \ker L}=\|x\|_Y+\|z\|_Y$$ As $Y/\ker L=X$ we get  $X\oplus\ker L=Y.$ The mapping $U:X\oplus \ker L\to Y$ defined by $$U(x\oplus z)=x+z$$ is a bijection. Moreover $U$ is  bounded because $$\|U(x\oplus z)\|_Y=\|x+z\|_Y\le \|x\|_Y+\|z\|_Y=\|x\oplus z\|_{X\oplus \ker L}$$ The mapping is thus invertible by the inverse mapping theorem. Hence $$\|x\|_Y+\|z\|_Y=\|x\oplus z\|_{X\oplus \ker L}\le d\|x+z\|_Y$$
This shows that $\ker L$ is a complementary subspace of $X.$

The converse implication is slightly easier. Assume $X$ is closed in $Y.$ Thus $J$ is a continouous bijection from $(X\,\|\cdot\|_X)$ to  $(X\,\|\cdot\|_Y).$ By the inverse mapping theorem the inverse mapping is continuous, i.e.
$$\|x\|_X\le c\|x\|_Y,\quad x\in X$$ for a positive constant $c.$ Therefore  the norms $\|\cdot \|_X$ and $\|\cdot \|_Y$ are equivalent on $X.$  Assume $X\oplus V=Y$ where $V$ is a closed complementary subspace for $X.$ Let $X\oplus V$ be equipped with the norm $\|x+v\|=\|x\|_Y+\|v\|_Y.$ The mapping $U:X\oplus V\to Y$ is a bijection. By the inverse mapping theorem the mapping $U^{-1}:Y\to X\oplus V$ is bounded which  means
that for any $x\in X$ and $v\in V$ we have
$$\|x\|_Y+\|v\|_Y\le d\|x+v\|_Y,\quad x\in X,\ v\in V$$
Define $R:Y\to X$ by $R(x+v)=x.$ Then $R$ is bounded as
$$\|R(x+v)\|_X=\|x\|_X\le c\|x\|_Y\le cd\|x+v\|_Y$$ and
$RJx=Rx=x,$ for $x\in X.$